# How to disable the required tag on a selectOneMenu when p:ajax event=change?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, required

Here is my configuration:

- PrimeFaces: 4.0.4 (elite)
- OmniFaces: 1.6.3
- JSF: MyFaces 2.0.2
- Server: WebSphere 8.5.0.2

Some code (I only post the relevant part for better clarity):

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{viewModel.selectedContact}" required="true" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{viewModel.updateContact}" update="area"/> 
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg.no_contact}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{viewModel.contacts}"/> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So here, we have a simple `p:selectOneMenu` that contains a list of `Contact` objects as well as a "No Contact" option. This field is required if I want to submit the form.

When a contact is selected in the list, the `updateContact` method is called. This method will generate data that will be displayed in the `area` section of the page updated by the AJAX call.

If I select the "No Contact" option, a validation error is triggered as this field is required, so the `updateContact` method is not called. I would like the method to be called as I would need to reset some data then hide the `area` section of the page.

I have tried using `process="@this"`, `immediate="true"`, but it doesn't work. With `immediate="true"`, the selected `Contact` is not passed to the `updateContact` method.

So, what is the best way to bypass the validation of this field when selecting a null value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the `required` attribute check if the command button is invoked. You can check that by the presence of the button's client ID in the request parameter map.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" />
...
<p:commandButton binding="#{save}" ... />
```

*(note: code is as-is, you don't need a bean property for this)*

If the command button is not invoked (but instead the ajax change listener is invoked), then the `required` attribute will evaluate `false` and everything will go as you intented.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you intend to make them appear like required during render response all time. So, just add that check:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... required="#{not empty param[save.clientId] or facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}" />
...
<p:commandButton binding="#{save}" ... />
```

Comment: What you propose is a good solution. However, I have a remark. All my required fields on the form have an associated `p:outputLabel` with a `for` attribute. That means they will display a little star (*) next to them, showing the user those fields are required. If I use your solution, those stars are not displayed anymore. The user will see them only after submitting the form.